# AutoHotKey on Windows is sometimes not capturing key press

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, cpu-usage, microsoft

I am using `reneo.exe`, application downloaded from [www.neo-layout.org](https://www.neo-layout.org). Application is programmed using AutoHotKey (AHK). It is capturing all keypresses and sending own output.

It works well, but sometimes, window independent, the output is also direct key pressed. E.g., under "q" key is mapped "x". When I press "q", it should write "x". Most of times is is working, but sometimes I got "qx", or just "q", instead of "x".

I am using also my own AHK scripts, and rarely I saw this issue also there. I found that issue is present mostly by start of typing word or sentence, like application is sleeping and it takes time to wake up. It is also usually (but not only) happen, when there is high CPU (PC fan is noisely and computer generally react slow).

I tried to change priority of `reneo.exe` to realtime, but without help.
Most busy process is `MsMpEng.exe`, which I am not able to end, change priority, or change affinity and I can not uninstall it. I suggest that it is antivirus.

I guess is a Windows issue and I hope there will be soli
ution to change some settings, or disable, restrict, or raise priority some other process, which is responsible by communication between `reneo.exe`, AHK module, Windows and keyboard output.

I am facing this issue years, but it is worse and worse. Let us say, that it is doing every day in 8hrs shift. After each time I restart the computer to kill `MsMpEng` process. After restarting computer also whole PC is reacting more quickly.

Comment: You should speak to the developers of the misbehaving application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please give your question some form.

Comment: You can [exclude](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26) Autohotkey.exe  from Windows Defender and also reneo.exe, if you trust it.

Comment: You're right, `MsMpEng.exe` is Microsoft Malware Protection Engine. Here are a couple of suggestions how to prevent it from hogging the resources: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-msmpeng-exe-why-is-it-of-high-cpu-disk-usage/

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. The summary question is: "How do I ensure that after the key is pressed, an event in the AHK instead of a standard operating system event is carried out?"

Comment: If a program is running with admin privileges, then AHK won't intercept the key presses, and that could be the reason behind this problem. If that is the case, try to [run the AHK script as administrator](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs).

Comment: user3419297, I ran always AHK under administration privileges. If not, it is not working where admin windows are activated, e.g. Task Manager. But this is different issue. My issue is happening randomly, not just in specific window.

Comment: user3419297, thank you, but exclude from Windows Defender, nor the app, neighter process, did not help.

Comment: `Process, Priority,, H` `SetBatchLines -1` `#KeyHistory 0` `ListLines Off` , improve the performance and the speed of the script